# How to read large files line by line?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract data from csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

I need to do it for a huge CSV file with help of PHP.

Comment: Possible dupe, alright, but I like this one more than originals :)

Comment: check my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22744300/2037323 which includes some comparisons also

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) function. It gets a line from file pointer and parse for CSV fields.

Following example reads a CSV file `myfile.csv`, gets the records and displays them line by line.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
//open the file
if (($handle = fopen("myfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)
        {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: @Brent: Yes, why *reinvent the wheel* if there is already a good example.

Comment: On the same grounds, why answer when it has been already answered ;) closevote please

Comment: @Gordon, I did not know that it is already answered on StackOverflow. I have started answering things here for last 15-20 days only.

Comment: SO may be more important than original literature.