# Importing Large CSV file in MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import a 60,000 or more rows in a CSV file. The code can import a 5000 lines only. Someone can help me?

```
require_once('connection.php');

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (EntryId_Pk, AccessCode, MobileNumber, TelcoCode, TIN, ORNo, ORAmt, NumOfEntries, ECN, AddedOn) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Comment: Your whole post doesn't contains a single question about a programming problem. What's your problem?

Comment: wouldn't a `while` loop not being better than a `do while` here? ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Agreed, unless there is always a first row guaranteed. Also, I'm going to give the usual spiel regarding mysql_* being deprecated and should not be used. Everytime you use that lib, Rasmus Lerdorf eats a kitten.

Comment: @Zarathuztra If there would be no rows a while loop would just not being entered

Comment: @hek2mgl Exactly, that's what I'm getting at. IN this case, while would work just fine.

Comment: @user3315577 Are you receiving any errors? $data could be causing you to hit a memory limit.

Comment: my situation is that when i am importing a large csv file. it doesn't continue. sorry a php begginer here. :(

Comment: @Zarathuztra no error messages at all.

Comment: check my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22744300/2037323 which includes some comparisons also

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use the [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) MySQL statement. This can be really fast since you don't need to read everything into PHP-land and let MySQL be smart about the allocations. You can use it something like this from PHP:

```
// dont use mysql_* anymore in new code
mysqli_query($dblink, '
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
        INTO TABLE transactions
        FIELDS TERMINATED by ","
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "\'"
        LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
');
```

Comment: That's the prefered solution +1 However, in shared hosting environment this might not being allowed

Comment: Where should I put this? Thank you for all of your answers. :)

Comment: This would replace the `do { ... } while` loop in your code. You will still need the csv file's path itself as the parameter after the `INFILE`.

Comment: @complex857 I will try this at the best as I can. Perhaps, Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @shijin, If you use `LOCAL` keyword then the file is read by the client and it should work with a remote server (the mysql*d* don't have to see the file). For this to work both the server and the client have to allow this. See more about the [LOCAL in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), there's a paragraph starting with LOCAL around the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timeout error. Try to set

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Also could be a good practice to import the data in chunks and insert multiple rows within a query instead of doing it row by row.