# read big file with php line by line (csv file generated on a mac)

Tags: php, sql, csv, utf-8

How can I read a big file in php (csv file) line by line to avoid getting out of memory?
At the moment, I have this :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)
```

I'm nearly sure my php reads lines one by one :

```
$i = 0;
    $source = fopen('falkcsvutf.csv', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 0, ";")) !== FALSE && $i < 10)
    {
        echo $data[1];
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($source);
```

*$i < 10 is there only to limit in debugging...*

I have the feeling php things there is only one line in my csv, however, when I open the file in sublime text, I see all the lines (with line numbering)

The file is a Excel file, saved to CSV, then converted to utf8 with iconv function.

any idea?

Comment: This happens to me sometimes on localhost but not on our live server, I have no idea how to fix on localhost.

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? If so, take heed of the `auto_detect_line_endings` note in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: This is on a live (linux) server, but file was generated on mac

Comment: @VincentDuprez try `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);`

Comment: @MarkBaker  you got it! put it as an answer please

Comment: check my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22744300/2037323 which includes some comparisons also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

So check the value of `auto_detect_line_endings`