# Reading a 6MB csv file in PHP - Memory exhausted

Tags: php, file, csv, memory, import

I'm trying to open/read a 6MB CSV file with PHP like so:

`$lines = file("/path/to/my/file.csv");`

But I'm getting the following error:

`PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6461150 bytes) in /path/to/php_file.php on line 488`

As you can see, our PHP memory settings are set to 1GB (dedicated server, not limited by any shared hosting package etc).

My question is should a **6MB CSV file** *really* be using **over 1GB** when read into a variable (array). I'm just a bit confused because I'm *sure* I've opened larger CSV files with PHP before without problems on this server.

Shouldn't make a difference but we're using **PHP 5.3** on **Ubuntu 12.04 Server**.

Comment: Is that the only thing the script is doing? Is there a reason you need the full file in memory?

Comment: The script does do some stuff before (to big to post the entire thing on here), but this is the line it's failing on. I'll have a quick scan through and see if I can spot anything else which may be "wasting" memory. We're looping through the file doing some basic processing on each line.

Comment: Calling `http://uk1.php.net/memory_get_usage` before the `file` line may help track it down.

Comment: Thanks. I unset a few variables which were no longer needed before the call and it's now working fine :) It's still using nearly 1GB of memory somehow before the call according to `memory_get_usage` :/ so need to look into that. But it takes it under the limit enough for this to work. Thanks again!

Comment: check my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22744300/2037323 which includes some comparisons also

Answer (score 1):

You should process the csv line by line to prevent memory exhaustion. Try something like this:

```
$f = fopen("my.csv", "r");
if(true === is_resource($f))
{
    while(false === feof($f))
    {
        $line = fgetcsv($f, 8192);
        // do something with the data here
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

Using fgetcsv() to parse the csv is also far easier than using file().

Answer (score -2):

Try to restart the apache server.

Comment: It's a production server. I'd really like to avoid kicking off a few hundred users unless I really need to. If you can suggest any way of seeing if this would help beforehand (viewing total used memory, etc) then I'd be interested in looking into that.