# Reach big csv file and work on csv file part by part

Tags: php, memory

I have a CSV file with 35k records. If i pull all data to memory it will break the page. How do i handle such cases. I need to reach each line and read particular column data and do some validation and if it fails it will written to a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520093/read-large-data-from-csv-file-in-php this may helpful for you

Comment: I may be wrong (and perhaps this function doesn't even exist in PHP), but I believe this is what `Seek` can be used for. It will allow you to start reading the file from any point you want.