# Read a csv file between 2 rows using php

Tags: php

I am try to read a csv file which has 200000 records, and then using loop to insert the record which is quite very slow.

So I want to read the file by 10k. Like first read 1 to 10k and in second time read 10k to 20k and so on.

I have done the following

```
$row1 = fgetcsv($handle, $delimiter);
$endNumber = 8635;

for ($i = $start; $i < $endNumber; $i++) {
    fgets($handle);
}
```

It is used to skip the record but it is not working as i need and also used this

```
for($i = 8; $row = fgetcsv($handle, $delimiter); $i++) {
        if($i === $endNumber) {
            fclose($handle);
           return $rowy;
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read large data from csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520093/read-large-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

Comment: @B001 it is not same it is csv filw with number of record not with size of file

Comment: Go through the answers there is a reference to another answer

Comment: @B001 I have checked that and then after say that

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile give an alternative.  Load the file to a work table and then process it.