# Reading CSV in PHP and out put its contents by array value

Tags: php, variables, csv

I want to display the contents of a CSV file by assigning it to a variable and then display it using echo statement.

This code is not working could someone point the error in it

```
   $fh = fopen('db.csv', 'r');
   $now = time();
   $data=fgetcsv($fh);
   $data[0]=$name;
   echo $name;
```

Am a newbie to coding and scripting.
Thanks

This is the CSV line that I want to be printed

```
    katz,26-11-2011,http//www.google.com
```

Comment: Can you pleas add some sample line from your CSV?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract data from csv file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+read+csv+file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you first valorize the `$data` with an array of your CSV and then you overwrite the first position with the `$name` variable (which apparently is null)?

```
$data[0] = $name;
```

should be

```
$name = $data[0];
```

Comment: @Gordon It actually exists :P http://www.thefreedictionary.com/valorize, @Vinner accept the answer if it fits your request!

Comment: oh, I wasnt saying it doesnt exist. I just didnt knew the word before, hence my comment that I learned a new word :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the handy [fgetcvs function for this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Might as well post an example for want of a complete answer, shamelessly ripped from that same 
manpage:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Hope that fits your needs. Happy coding.

Comment: It's exactly what he's doing!

Comment: @Nicola -> Yeah. It looks similar but there is a difference, this one is fully expected to work. Tested & tried by millions.