# Split CSV file with unix timestamps into 7 different csv files

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have a large 2 column csv file ("data.csv") with a weeks worth of data.
Column one has unix time stamps
Column two has strings:

```
1329548400,cats
1329548400,dogs
1329550200,fish
1329550200,cats
1329552000,dogs
1329552000,fish
1329584400,cats
1329584400,dogs
1329550200,cats
```

Via php, I need to convert data.csv into 7 files, Sunday.csv, Monday.csv...Saturday.csv

If I could grab each row, I know I can do something like

```
$temp = "data.csv";
$fileName = array_unique($temp);
foreach ($fileName as $row) {
    $theDay = date("Y", $row[firstcolumn]);
    if ($theDay == "Sunday") {
        $fileToWriteTo = "Sunday.csv";
        $f = fopen($fileToWriteTo, "a");
        fwrite($fileToWriteTo, $row . "\n");
        fclose($fileToWriteTo);
        }
    if ($theDay == "Monday") {
        $fileToWriteTo = "Monday.csv";
        $f = fopen($fileToWriteTo, "a");
        fwrite($fileToWriteTo, $row . "\n");
        fclose($fileToWriteTo);
        }
    }
```

Problem is

1) I don't know how to read each row of data.csv, assuming the syntax above is wrong
2) I admit Im a bit of a php laymen :)

...how far off am I? Am I even in the ballpark?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract data from csv file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

Comment: There is a special function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) which might come in handy for you ʘ͜ʘ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, don't [open file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) at each iteration do it before loop.

```
$fps = array(); // fps = File Pointers
$days = array( 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', ...);
foreach( $days as $key => $name){
    $fps[ $name] = fopen( 'a', $name . '.csv');
    if( !$fps[ $name]){
        die("Cannot open $name.csv");
    }

    // Although I wouldn't rely on date's `l` format, because
    // it can be localized and script may just stop working
    // and rather use:
    $fps[ $key] = fopen( 'a', $name . '.csv');
    if( $fps[ $key])...
    // Sunday = 7 = 0, Monday = 1...
}
```

Now, you'll address fields via [`date( 'w')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), which will give numbers 0 - Sunday, 6 - Saturday:

```
$day = date( 'w', $timestamp);
```

About making unique results... You'll probably need to use function like [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and store all processed rows in one array.

About reading and writing CSV files, there are 2 functions: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) resp. [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). So entire loop:

```
$temp = "data.csv";
$rows = array(); // List of unique itemps
$fp = fopen( $temp, 'r') or die( "Cannot open `$temp` for reading");
// Put here loop which will open all 7 files as mentioned above
// Optionally skip first row (it may contain header)
fgets( $fp);

// Read each row
while( ($array = fgetcsv( $fp, 10000, ',', '"') !== false){
    // Check unique row
    $row = implode( ',', $array);
    if( in_array( $row, $rows)){
         continue; // Skip this iteration
    }
    $rows[] = $row;

    $day = date( 'w', $array[0]);
    fputcsv( $fps[$day], $array);
}
```

And don't forget to [close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) all files:

```
fclose( $fp);
foreach( $fps as $fp){
    fclose( $fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from a file you need to create a handle to read that file and then get each line and then parse.

```
$handle = fopen('data.csv','r');
while($line = fgets($handle)){
   //Do any parsing here.
   $array = explode(',',$line);
   $timestamp = $array[0];
   $string = $array[1];
   //Do whatever else you need to do with it.
}
```

Try reading this if you want to create more files from one file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Waaaah! Every time somebody reads and explodes a CSV file instead of using fgetCSV() an elephpant dies

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do the job. I haven't tested it.

```
$temp = "data.csv";
$fileData = file($temp);
$errors = 0;
$days = Array(fopen('Sunday.csv','a+'),
              fopen('Monday.csv','a+'),
              fopen('Tuesday.csv','a+'),
              fopen('Wednesday.csv','a+'),
              fopen('Thursday.csv','a+'),
              fopen('Friday.csv','a+'),
              fopen('Saturday.csv','a+'));
foreach($days as $fd) $errors += ($fd === FALSE);
if( ! $errors)
{
    foreach ($fileData as $row) {
        $columns=explode(',',$row);
        $theDay = date("w", $columns[0]);
        if(empty($days[$theDay])) continue; // maybe not valid date
        fwrite($days[$theDay], $row."\n");
    }
}
else
{
    echo "I couldn't open $errors of the files\n";
}
foreach($days as $fd) if($fd !== FALSE) fclose($fd);
```

Comment: Yeah open and close file in each iteration, way to go! *</sarcasm>* :)

Comment: You're right. Maybe I had to put the file descriptor in the $days array and close them at the end.

Comment: Not checking whether file was opened successfully .)) (use @Vyktor so I'll get notice about the comment)

Comment: THIS...is what I needed:

$columns=explode(',',$row);
theDay = date("w", $columns[0]);

Should work fine...thanks all...!