# Parse CSV with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, csv, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract data from csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

i'm new on php and now i try to make a private site for me and read out some stock information over yahoo api

Link: `finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^GDAXI+^TECDAX+eurusd=x+gcf12.cmx+CLH12.NYM&f=nl1k2`

The link works fine but now how can i read this file out? And echo the information on my page?

Output:

```
"DAX",6864.43,"+54.97 - +0.81%"
"TECDAX",775.33,"+3.78 - +0.49%"
"EUR to USD",1.3447,"N/A - 0.00%"
"Gold Jan 12",1731.80,"N/A - +0.32%"
"Crude Oil Mar 12",105.88,"N/A - +0.04%"
```

What i need:

```
echo $name;
echo $rate;
echo $change;
echo $changeinpercent;
```

I hope some one can help me, and sry for my bad english.

Greetings,
matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RegEx to extract from each line the information you need. The following php code is what you need to extract this specific data. It's a RegEx code and you should use it with a preg_match function:

```
/\"([^\"]+)\",(\d+\.\d+),\"(N\/A)?([+-]?\d+\.?\d+)?\s+-\s+([+-]?\d+\.?\d+%?)/
```

It gives you an array, and you will use it as:

```
$match[0]  
$match[1]  
$match[2]  
$match[3]
```

UPDATE:
This is the code to do it:

```
<?php
$csv=file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^GDAXI+^TECDAX+eurusd=x+gcf12.cmx+CLH12.NYM&f=nl1k2");

$rows=explode("\n", $csv);

for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
{
    preg_match_all("/\"([^\"]+)\",(\d+\.\d+),\"(N\/A)?([+-]?\d+\.?\d+)?\s+-\s+([+-]?\d+\.?\d+%?)/", $rows[$i],$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
}
?>
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "DAX",6864.43,"+54.97 - +0.81%
            [1] => DAX
            [2] => 6864.43
            [3] => 
            [4] => +54.97
            [5] => +0.81%
        )  
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Gold Jan 12",1731.80,"N/A - +0.32%
            [1] => Gold Jan 12
            [2] => 1731.80
            [3] => N/A
            [4] => 
            [5] => +0.32%
        )

)
```

If it is N/A you will find it in $matches[3], if a value in 4. 
    )

Comment: but how can i connect that with my csv?

Comment: @matthias read every line of the csv file (with a for or while) and use a preg_match_all (for each line).

Comment: @matthias hopefully the edited answer will help you more :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [fgetscsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Comment: Please use the comment feature for one-liners.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP5.3 you can use [str_getcsv](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) although you will still need to parse the last string value as that contains two values you are looking for (hint: [explode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)).

If you're not on PHP5.3, you should be able to use [fgetcsv](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) with a stream passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should see the manual [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)
and then, see the following code pasted as example,

```
<?php 
// 
 // Convert csv file to associative array: 
 // 

function csv_to_array($input, $delimiter='|') 
 { 
     $header = null; 
     $data = array(); 
     $csvData = str_getcsv($input, "\n"); 

     foreach($csvData as $csvLine){ 
         if(is_null($header)) $header = explode($delimiter, $csvLine); 
         else{ 

             $items = explode($delimiter, $csvLine); 

             for($n = 0, $m = count($header); $n < $m; $n++){ 
                 $prepareData[$header[$n]] = $items[$n]; 
             } 

             $data[] = $prepareData; 
         } 
     } 

     return $data; 
 } 

//----------------------------------- 
 // 
 //Usage: 

$csvArr = csv_to_array(file_get_contents('test.csv')); 

?>
```

this code should help you a lot, but please save the file to CSV to use this function..and saving the file is not tough. and the source for the code is still the stated above [link](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) you just need to modify it as per your requirements..

HTH