# return a particular row of CSV file in form of array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract data from csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

I want to print an array from a CSV file. It contains 4 rows. First row with id numbers and second,third and fourth rows with corresponding values.

Depending on the values, I want to print the id number. Please help me guys as I am new to php.

Like if value == 1 , print_r($id)

but I am not sure how to point to that paticular id.

Comment: Do you want to add your code to the question?

Comment: [Do your homework please.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) How to read a CSV file has been asked and answered a dozen times.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), it will help you out tremendously

I've adapted the example in the PHP docs to closer match my understanding of your needs.

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle) !== false) {
        // assuming 'id' is the first column
        // if id is 1, output the row...
        if ($data[0] == 1) {
            print_r($data);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: print_r(fgetcsv($file)). this will print the CSV file. but what if what the data of a particular row?