# PHP csv parsing lib

Tags: php, parsing, file-io, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract data from csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

Does anyone know of a PHP csv parsing library / class that works with csv generated by all kinds of programs and ideally finds the separator automatically? Everything I tried so far fails with one file or another.

Comment: Trying to figure out separators automagically is virtually impossible reliably. You should ask the user what the format it or make him use a specific separator.

Comment: If it would be doable, why doesn't Microsoft Excel or OpenOffice automatically do the right thing when importing CSV? They should have the ressources to get it right if it was possible. I think it isn't, because "CSV" is an underspecified description of content - you need explicit info of the separation characters used.

Comment: [WebIt4Me/reader](https://github.com/webit4me/reader) provides a tool to read or search through CSV file

Answer (score 3):

There are native functions, such as [`str_getcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Remember to [be a better PHP developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/) and RTM.

Comment: -1 for omitting the `F`. Four letter words aren't fun without the `F`.

Comment: @rambo coder. LOL. I originally had it. But felt my suggestion read *harshly*, so I removed it.