# Parse a CVS-like file in PHP and store it as a dictionary

Tags: php

I have text file that I am generating that looks like this:

```
ipaddress,host
ipaddress,host
ipaddress,host
ipaddress,host
ipaddress,host
...
```

How could i read through this file and store each line as a key value pair?

ex.

```
array{
       [ipaddress]=>[host]
       [ipaddress]=>[host]
       [ipaddress]=>[host]
       ..........
     }
```

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @airza, why? I wouldn't use regular expressions here, it is simple string split.

Comment: Yeah that would be better.

Comment: Do some of the work before you posts an easy question. At least say, "This is what I have, what am I doing wrong?" This isn't like a homework completion site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching through a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249018/php-searching-through-a-csv-file-the-oop-way/13287221#13287221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = file('myfile.txt');
$ips = array();

foreach($arr as $line){
  list($ip, $host) = explode(',',$line);
  $ips[$ip]=$host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution:

```
<?php
    $hosts = file('hosts.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $results = array();
    foreach ($hosts as $h) {
        $infos = explode(",", $h);
        $results[$infos[0]] = $infos[1];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the function [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
//open a file handler
$file = file("path_to_your_file.txt");

//init an array for keys and values
$keys= array();
$values = array();

//loop through the file
foreach($file as $line){

    //explode the line into an array
    $lineArray = explode(",",$line);

    //save some keys and values for this line
    $keys[] = $lineArray[0];
    $values[] = $lineArray[1];
}

//combine the keys and values
$answer = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("ip-hosts.txt", "r");
$result = array();
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $t = explode(',', $buffer);
        $result[$t[0]] = $t[1];
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
// debug:
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>"
?>
```