# What is the best way to loop through a huge csv file

Tags: php, excel, loops, csv

I am making a system that is reading huge csv files and is storing the data of them in a database. With huge files I mean 90 csv files with 30000 rows in each file. And every row has around the 30-40 columns.

I was wondering what the fastest way was to loop trough all those files.

Currently I was using the default build-in csv reader. But I dont know if that is the fastest/most efficient way.

Does someone know a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table might help

Comment: I had the same task a few weeks ago and what I did was use multi-threading. I don't know if it's the best approach but it does my task faster.

Comment: Check out this answer — http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287221/487923