# PHP and CSV file - how to detect end of line?

Tags: php, file, csv, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract data from csv file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

I have some data in XLS, I save them as CSV, the delimiter is **comma*.
Then I am trying to load the data from this CSV file:

```
$input = explode("\r\n", fread($file, filesize("my_data.csv")));
print_r($input);
```

The output:

```
Array ( [0] => data from the CSV file)
```

This is the problem - in the array is always just one item, where are printed out all data from the CSV file. How is that possible? Why isn't in the array as much items as is rows in the CSV file?

Also, I've tried to change `"\r\n"` for "\n", but it's the same.

What I am trying to do - load each line from the CSV file and this each line to process.

**EXAMPLE OF THE FILE:**

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

**OUTPUT:**

`a,b,c,d e,f,g,h`

Comment: Use the built in fgetcsv() function for reading CSV data

Comment: Any reason you are not using http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php ?  Don't try to parse CSV data by yourself -you'll be in for a world of pain with anything more complex than a simple list of numbers.

Comment: But guys, how do you solve the last item on the row? Because, this last item has any comma in the end, so the last item is merged with the first item on the second line.

Comment: @user984621: CSV reading is a solved problem.  Use the `fgetcsv` function that has already been written, tested and debugged, rather than writing your own code that you will have to write, test and debug.

Comment: Guys, sorry if this is too stupid question and that's the reason why you want to close the question, but above I described the problem for which I just didn't figure out...

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using php's built in csv file reading function `fgetcsv()` and not create your own:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
 if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = implode (",",$data); //puts back together the row from the csv
        echo $row. "\n"; //assuming you want a visual linebreak on console, add the \n
     }
    fclose($handle);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or, but when I try this, so the last item in the line has not a comma in the end - what getting me into troubles... because I don't get expected output.

Comment: Ray, please checkout the OP, this is the output that I get if I will use this snippet -- the letter `d` and `e` are merged into one item. That's my whole problem that I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue:

In the XLS file, before exporting the file into CSV, I added in the end of sheet one more column with the char `'`.