# Parsing a CSV file into a two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv

my goal of this is to put the first index (first value of each line in the csv) into a dropdown html `select` list.

test.csv

```
mark, blue, tall,
mike, black, short
```

index.php

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("csv/food.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "<pre>";
}
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => mark
    [1] => blue
    [2] => tall
    [3] => mike
    [4] => black
    [5] => short
)
```

output if I remove comma after tall

```
Array
(
    [0] => mark
    [1] => blue
    [2] => tall
mike
    [3] => black
    [4] => short
)
```

**desired output**

```
Array
(
    [0][0] => mark
    [0][1] => blue
    [0][2] => tall
    [1][0] => mike
    [1][1] => black
    [1][2] => short
)
```

Comment: thats mean there is no actual new lines in your csv file. try to remove comma after "Tall," in the first line.

Comment: I tried that, but then it just puts `tall mike` into `[2]`. I'll update OP with output from what you suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract data from csv file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php)

Comment: And you downvoted me for it? Gee, thanks buddy.

Comment: Welp, that thread solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working:

```
<select name="list" > 
<?php 
$file = fopen("food.csv", "r"); 

while (!feof($file) ) { 
    $lines = fgetcsv($file, 1024);?> 
    <option value="<?php print $lines[0] ?>"> <?php print $lines[0] ?> </option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
<?php 
fclose($file); 
?>
```