# php read text file and comparing it with user input

Tags: php, html, file-io

I have a text file called login.txt and I want to compare the id and password with the user's input with the one saved in the text file. I'm stuck with the php file. Any help will be appreciated.

login.txt

```
Brian,brianpass\n
Adam,adampass\n
Bob,bobpass\n
```

login.htm

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<form id="regform" method="get" action="login.php">
<p>Manager ID:<input type="text" name="mid" required="required" /></p>
<p>Password:<input type="password" name="mpassword" required="required" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$mid       = trim(@$_POST["mid"]);
$mpassword = trim(@$_POST["mpassword"]);

if ($mid != NULL && $mpassword != NULL)
{
    $str = file("login.txt");
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($str as $value)
    {
        $array = (explode(",", $value));        
        $newArray[$array[0]] =  trim($array[1]);
    }
}
?>
```

Question: I want the system to determine if the login process is successful or failed and echo it.

Comment: I hope that this is for testing/educational purposes.

Comment: PHP already supports CSV, no need to re-invent the whell, see [how to extract data from csv file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2805427/367456)

Comment: Yeah, its a lab exercise for uni. Not gonna implement it in real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is how I would do it. Firstly, you have to change the form method from `get` to `post`.

**login.txt**

```
Brian,brianpass
Adam,adampass
Bob,bobpass
```

**test.php** - *I did this as a single page app, you can split this if you want, but the concept is still same*

```
<?php

// Handle Post
if (count($_POST))
{
    // Parse login.txt
    $loginData = file('login.txt');
    $accessData = array();
    foreach ($loginData as $line) {
        list($username, $password) = explode(',', $line);
        $accessData[trim($username)] = trim($password);
    }

    // Parse form input
    $mid = isset($_POST['mid']) ? $_POST['mid'] : '';
    $mpassword = isset($_POST['mpassword']) ? $_POST['mpassword'] : '';

    // Check input versus login.txt data
    if (array_key_exists($mid, $accessData) && $mpassword == $accessData[$mid]) {
        echo "Username and Password is correct";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid username and/or password";
    }
}

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    <form id="regform" method="post" action="">
        <p>Manager ID:<input type="text" name="mid" required="required" /></p>
        <p>Password:<input type="password" name="mpassword" required="required" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested this and it works. For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing the get and post, I was wondering why nothing came on screen and thats the reason. @Latheesan

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you save passwords this way (naked), but since you already got the exploding per line, you could just compare them:

```
if($array[0] == $mid && $array[1] == $mpassword) {
    // match
} else {
    // did not match
}
```

Sidenote: I suggest at least using a hashing function. I'd recommend using mysql tables with PHP 5.5's [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) functions or use the [password compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for lesser PHP versions.

Comment: I assume your answer is placed after $newArray[$array[0]] =  trim($array[1]);, am I correct? It just happens to be passwords, but yeah, in real world applications I wont store passwords like that. @Ghost

Comment: @bisonsausage actually you rally don't needthose `$newArray ...`, just put this condition inside the loop

Comment: +1 and for mentioning about safe password hashing methods.

Comment: *Oh*, and OP was using `method="get"` instead of POST ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah at my first skim i didn't notice until i saw the accepted answer

Comment: I'd have to setup the whole thing to test OP's initial code. I sure hope that OP is using this for testing/educational purposes. You already know the possible/probable outcome if OP is ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow taking that extra mile lol. it would be a disaster if someone peeks on the textfile. and i don't get the logic trying to put it inside another container

Comment: Most of the time I have to test actual code to make 100% sure. Many a time, the errors are obvious. If OP is using this as an actual working model, then I'm hoping the OP will be reading this, because it's just a matter of time before the OP's site gets hacked, unfortunately.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well if the question is easy and not cumbersome to reproduce, yeah i test is on my env as well. lets just hope this is just some coding exercise.

Comment: I'm afraid that changing to a POST method along with OP's code and your suggestion Ghost, did not work. Thought you might like to know. Latheesan's answer worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yep, its totally coding exercise. In the exercise, I'm supposed to read it from a text file and another one from xml file. Not gonna implement it in real world.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution have security problem and easily can exploit, so for more security on user input data view this link :
[enter link description here](http://www.dreamhost.com/dreamscape/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/)

for comparing write

```
foreach ($str as $value)
{
    $array = (explode(",", $value));        

    if(trime($array[0]) == $mid && trime($array[1]) == $mpassword) {
         // match
     } else {
       // did not match
         }
}
```

But Do not recommend this way for Login system ,if have a limitation  on use database at least use hash and encrypt solutions such as RSA,hash,md5(recommend: it is one way)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $mid = @trim($_POST["mid"]);
    $mid = stripslashes($mid);
    $mpassword = @trim($_POST["mpassword"]);
    $mpassword = stripslashes($mpassword);
    $mid_pass = $mid.",".$mpassword."\n";//remove this \n if you remove it from file

    @override
    if ($mid != NULL && $mpassword != NULL)
    {
        $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++){
         if($mid_pass == $lines[$i]){
            echo "success";//Use your code here
            break;
         }else{
            echo "failed";//use your code here
         }
        }
    }
?>
```