# Php file function does not work on long csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am using:

```
$csv = file($filePathTest);
```

where $filePathTest is path to this csv:

```
policyID,statecode,county,eq_site_limit,hu_site_limit,fl_site_limit,fr_site_limit,tiv_2011,tiv_2012,eq_site_deductible,hu_site_deductible,fl_site_deductible,fr_site_deductible,point_latitude,point_longitude,line,construction,point_granularity
119736,FL,CLAY COUNTY,498960,498960,498960,498960,498960,792148.9,0,9979.2,0,0,30.102261,-81.711777,Residential,Masonry,1
448094,FL,CLAY COUNTY,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1438163.57,0,0,0,0,30.063936,-81.707664,Residential,Masonry,3
206893,FL,CLAY COUNTY,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,192476.78,0,0,0,0,30.089579,-81.700455,Residential,Wood,1
```

and the result of file($filePathTest) is correctly:

```
(array) [4 elements]
0: (string) "policyID,statecode,county,eq_site_limit,hu_site_limit,fl_site_limit,fr_site_limit,tiv_2011,tiv_2012,eq_site_deductible,hu_site_deductible,fl_site_deductible,fr_site_deductible,point_latitude,point_longitude,line,construction,point_granularity
"
1: (string) "119736,FL,CLAY COUNTY,498960,498960,498960,498960,498960,792148.9,0,9979.2,0,0,30.102261,-81.711777,Residential,Masonry,1
"
2: (string) "448094,FL,CLAY COUNTY,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1322376.3,1438163.57,0,0,0,0,30.063936,-81.707664,Residential,Masonry,3
"
3: (string) "206893,FL,CLAY COUNTY,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,190724.4,192476.78,0,0,0,0,30.089579,-81.700455,Residential,Wood,1"
```

The problem is, when I use a big csv file of 36000 rows the function file($filePathTest) return not correctly an array with a single element that include all the csv. I cannot understand why!

```
 (array) [1 element]
 0: (string)"All the csv file inside here "
```

Comment: Wouldn't reading it line by line be a better approach with large files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php

Comment: I have the same issue also line by line

Comment: Using `fgetcsv()` does it try and have all columns in the first row?

Comment: Yes with fgetcsv is all in one raw!!

Comment: This is really strange

Comment: I know this is a guess, but can you load it into an editor and remove everything but the first few lines, save it and try with the short file.

Comment: with the short file works fine, this make me more crazy

Comment: Have you tried loading the file into the editor and just saving it again.  It may be the end of line encoding which an editor will sometimes fix.